# How to connect to PostgreSQL from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database and make some queries. Though I have read a few threads here, the docs, and other blogs, I'm unable to make it works.

My function looks like this:

```js
const postgreSQL = require('pg');

const config = {
  host: 'host',
  database: 'db',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  port: 0000,
  max: 5, // max number of clients in the pool
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
};
let pool = new postgreSQL.Pool(config);

//.........other code.........

function CheckGeometryType(pool, tableName, column) {

  const schema = 'schema';
  let geometryValue = undefined;
  pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    client.query(`SELECT ST_GeometryType(${column})
                  AS geometryType FROM ${schema}.${tableName} LIMIT 1`);
    done(err);
    if (err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong. ' + err);
    }
    console.log("Result: " + queryResult.rows[0]);
    switch (queryResult) {
      // do things with result
    }
    done();
  });

  return geometryValue;
}
```

I've tried to do a `console.log()` inside the *SWITCH*, after/before *done()*,  but it's not executed. I have printed all SQL queries formed on the string I pass to *pool.query* on `pgAdmin` and all works and return the expected values I want to get.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

--- Edit ---

Thanks for the answers, but I'm still being unable to make it work. I've tried both methods but it isn't works. Looking at the [Documentation](https://node-postgres.com/guides/upgrading#client-query-submittable-) I'm trying this method.

The code is:

```js
let client = new Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
const query = client.query(new Query('SELECT ST_GeometryType($1) FROM $2.$3 LIMIT 1', [column, schema, tableName]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(query, null, 2)); //Debug purposes
query.on('row', (row) => {
    switch (row[0]) {
        case 'ST_LineString':
            geometryValue = 'LineString';
            break;
        case 'ST_MultiLineString':
            geometryValue = 'MultiLineString';
            break;
        case 'ST_Polygon':
            geometryValue = 'Polygon';
            break;
        case 'ST_MultiPolygon':
            geometryValue = 'MultiPolygon';
            break;
        case 'ST_Point':
            geometryValue = 'Point';
            break;
        case 'ST_MultiPoint':
            geometryValue = 'MultiPoint';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
query.on('end', (res) => {
    if(result.rows[0] === undefined){
        console.log('No data retrieved from DB');
    }
    client.end();
});
query.on('error', (res) => {
    console.log("Something went wrong: " + res);
});
```

Debugging, I can see that on *query* the values are stored fine:

```
{
  "text": "SELECT ST_GeometryType($1) FROM $2.$3 LIMIT 1",
  "values": [
    "column",
    "schema",
    "table"
  ],
  "portal": "",
  "_result": {
    "command": null,
    "rowCount": null,
    "oid": null,
    "rows": [],
    "fields": [],
    "_parsers": [],
    "RowCtor": null,
    "rowAsArray": false
  },
  "_results": {
    "command": null,
    "rowCount": null,
    "oid": null,
    "rows": [],
    "fields": [],
    "_parsers": [],
    "RowCtor": null,
    "rowAsArray": false
  },
  "isPreparedStatement": false,
  "_canceledDueToError": false,
  "_promise": null,
  "domain": null,
  "_events": {},
  "_eventsCount": 0
}
```

I've executed the query on pgAdmin an works fine, returning the desired result that I'm expecting but seems that trying to execute the query on the script doesn`t works.

What I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: You call done(err) rigth after the query, all the rest of your code is out of reach. Besides client.query needs a callback function as second argument, i guess. Insude the callback you call done(null, data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I did achieve what I want to do. After read more the [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) and use the new methods (some questions had the old version, Node version < 7.x) I finally made it work. I'm posting the solution to help someone who may have the same problem building their own script.

**This method uses the async/await form, so keep in mind that you will have to set all your functions to *async* and set *await* to the function that waits for the result inside of it, it's a chain from the function that connects with the DB to the top.**

```js
# Main file

#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
const geometryTypeFinder = require("./modules/geometryTypeFinder");


readParametersFromConsole();

async function readParametersFromConsole() {
  ........ code ........
  
  
  processParameters(...params);
}


async function processParameters(...params) {
  ........ code ........
  
  transformation = await geometryTypeFinder.findGeometryType(transformation);

  ........ code ........

}

# Module file

'use strict';

const postgreSQL = require('pg');

module.exports = {
  findGeometryType: async function (transformation) {
    ........ code ........
    transformation.dataModel.entities = await FindGeometryType(...params);
    ........ code ........
  }
};

async function FindGeometryType(entities, geometricColumns) {
  ........ code ........

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfEntities; i++) {
    ........ code ........
    for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
        let column = columns[j];
        let geometryType = await GetGeometryType(tableName, column);
        ........ now I can work with the value of geometryType ........
      }
  }
}

async function GetGeometryType(tableName, column) {

  const schema = 'schema';
  let geometryValue = undefined;
  const config = {
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    host: 'host',
    database: 'db',
    port: 1234,
  };

  let client = new postgreSQL.Client(config);
  try {
    client.connect();
    const result = await client.query(`SELECT ST_GeometryType(${column}) AS geo_type FROM ${schema}.${tableName} LIMIT 1`);
    if (result.rows.length === 0) {
      console.log('No data retrieved from DB');
    } else {
      const geoType = result.rows[0].geo_type; #<--- I get the result
      ........ code to process the value ........
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error retrieving database information: ${error.name} -> ${error.stack}`);
  } finally {
    client.end();
  }

  return geometryValue;
}
```

I don't know if this it's the best way to achieve what I want, but as I'm forced to use NodeJS and I'm learning by myself NodeJS, this is the best I could make it. Any suggestion will be well received.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use raw acces with "pg" package:

```
pg.connect(connectionString, function (err, client, done) {
  if (err) {
    return handleErrors(done, err, res);
  }
  return client.query("UPDATE tab SET v1=($1)  WHERE k1=($2)", [value, key], 
    function (err, result) {
     return reloadData(res, client, done, err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I'm still stuck. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequelize  for PostgreSQL. Its very good Object-Relational Mapping(ORM) in Node.js.

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  // gimme postgres, please!
  dialect: 'postgres'
})

for more details check below link.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but as project requirements I can't add more dependencies because we already have "pg". I've updated my answer.